# Allauth with JWT

Tags: django, jwt, django-allauth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, dj-rest-auth

My project requires JWT authentication, but also allauth is needed. How can i get JWT tokens after login via socials? I have surfed the net completely and tired of seeking the answer, the last hope I have is here, i guess...

I tried using simple_jwt but didn`t get any result. Also used dj-rest-auth but it is complicated. I guess the clue in dj-rest-auth, but i cannot find out how to use it.

I got an answer from net with this example:

```
class GitHubLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GitHubOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = "http://localhost:8000/"
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

but it requires those 3 credentials: access_token, code and id_token. Surfing the net i haven`t found any proper answer(